# nginx + node.js = failed while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, node.js

I try to use Iframely. I install the self hosted version on my server ubuntu + nginx:
[https://iframely.com/docs/host][1]

When i start node like this:
`# node server`
 Iframely works well
Otherwise, i get a 502 bad gateway error.

## ERROR

In the log error:

```
2016/01/25 06:06:58 [error] 13265#0: *4476 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, server: iframely.custom.com, request: "GET /iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8061/iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb", host: "iframely.custom.com"
```

When i try:
`# curl -i 127.0.0.1:8061/iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb`

It confirm the error:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8061: Connection refused`

I begin with node and i understand that maybe node.js is not listening on port 8061.

When i try:
`netstat -pantu`

I don't see the port in question but others like this one used by another node.js app which works perfectly:

`tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:4567          127.0.0.1:60724         ESTABLISHED 12329/node`

## CONFIGURATION

My host configuration:

```
upstream iframely.custom.com {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:8061;
        keepalive 8;
}
server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name iframely.custom.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/iframely.custom.com;

        # Logs
        access_log /var/log/iframely.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/iframely.error_log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://iframely.custom.com/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                # Socket.IO Support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        # Exclude from the logs to avoid bloating when it's not available
        include drop.conf;

}
```

I have tried to change in the configuration localhost for 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't change anything.

How to keeps a node.js app alive: do i have to restart it forever?
Could it be a problem with ipv4 or ipv6?

Thank you in advance for any help.
jb

Comment: This is not SF question, it's a SO question, because your node.js application exits, thus it behaves faulty. nginx has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @drookie thank you for the suggestion. i open it on SO.